# How to make "bringToFront()" only to a specific view (Button)?

Tags: java, android

I have a ConstraintLayout that have some buttons, this ConstraintLayout (in some cases) is behind FrameLayout which hides him.

I need to bringToFront only one specific button from this ConstraintLayout and not all the buttons.

It should be noted that I can't bringToFront the button before I bringToFront the ConstraintLayout (Which is hidden) first. How Can I do that?

this is the ConstraintLayout :

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/inside_call_btns_cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <!--Buttons section-->
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/speaker_iv"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/speaker_selector"
        android:checked="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bonus_rl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bonus_rl"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></ToggleButton>


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/mute_iv"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mute_selector"
        android:checked="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bonus_rl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bonus_rl" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bonus_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/camera_switch_iv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


        <app.components.CircleImageView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/mic_flag_civ"
            android:layout_width="67dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/flag_united_states_of_america" />

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/bonus_rl_iv"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/bonus_rl_disabled" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera_switch_iv"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_switch"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/decline_rl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/decline_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <app.components.CircleImageView

        </app.components.CircleImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hang_up_iv"  
            ----
            ----
           ---- />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and then FrameLayout cover this ConstraintLayout and i need that only **bonus_rl** be in front

Comment: Post your xml layout file here. I don't understand why you'd try juggling views front and back instead of simply making their visibility to `View.GONE` & `View.VISIBLE`.

Comment: Because I need them to see from behind the FrameLayout , I can't just hide the buttons, i need to bring to front only one button  and not all of the buttons.

Comment: Yeah so create a function which will toggle visibility of all the buttons. You don't need to put extra stress on layout creation by having useless views on screen. You can only toggle button Visible that you need when you need it, and then toggle visibility GONE in case you don't. It'll be more optimal and less memory consuming than your current thing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
view.getParent().bringChildToFront(view);
view.getParent().requestLayout();
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working, i post the code, Maybe it will explain more

Comment: @Arik6 you can also set increase elevation by ViewCompat.setElevation(View, int)

Comment: please try always to give an explanation to the answer.